# How do I modify this intrinsics code going from YUV420 to RGB24 to output RGBA32

Tags: c, rgb, intrinsics, yuv, image-conversion

I find myself in the position of needing to really use intrinsics for the first time as optimization for image conversion. I found this project here: https://github.com/jabernet/YCbCr2RGB/blob/master/conversion.cpp  and it almost works, but my output target needs to be in r8g8b8a8 while this is outputting in r8g8b8.

I tried modifiying this bit here:

```
const __m128 rgb1_1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b1, g1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r1, b1, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 0, 0)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
const __m128 rgb1_2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g1, r1, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)), 
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b1, g1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)), 
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0)); 
const __m128 rgb1_3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r1, b1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 2, 2)), 
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g1, r1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)), 
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));

const __m128 rgb2_1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b2, g2, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r2, b2, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 0, 0)), 
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0)); 
const __m128 rgb2_2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g2, r2, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)), 
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b2, g2, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)), 
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0)); 
const __m128 rgb2_3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r2, b2, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 2, 2)), 
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g2, r2, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)), 
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));

const __m128 rgb3_1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b3, g3, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r3, b3, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 0, 0)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
const __m128 rgb3_2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g3, r3, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b3, g3, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
const __m128 rgb3_3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r3, b3, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 2, 2)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g3, r3, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));

const __m128 rgb4_1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b4, g4, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r4, b4, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 0, 0)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
const __m128 rgb4_2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g4, r4, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(b4, g4, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
const __m128 rgb4_3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(
                _mm_shuffle_ps(r4, b4, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 2, 2)),
                _mm_shuffle_ps(g4, r4, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)),
                _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));

const __m128i pack1l = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb1_1), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb1_2));
const __m128i pack1h = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb1_3), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb2_1));
const __m128i pack1 = _mm_packus_epi16(pack1l, pack1h);
    
const __m128i pack2l = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb2_2), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb2_3));
const __m128i pack2h = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb3_1), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb3_2));
const __m128i pack2 = _mm_packus_epi16(pack2l, pack2h);
    
const __m128i pack3l = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb3_3), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb4_1));
const __m128i pack3h = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb4_2), _mm_cvtps_epi32(rgb4_3));
const __m128i pack3 = _mm_packus_epi16(pack3l, pack3h);
const __m128i packAlpha = { 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF };
    
    // and finally store in output
    
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(pixels + ((wh - width) * 4) - h * width * 4 + w * 4 + 0 * 16), pack1);
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(pixels + ((wh - width) * 4) - h * width * 4 + w * 4 + 1 * 16), pack2);
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(pixels + ((wh - width) * 4) - h * width * 4 + w * 4 + 2 * 16), pack3);
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(pixels + ((wh - width) * 4) - h * width * 4 + w * 4 + 3 * 16), packAlpha);
```

with the packAlpha lines added by me. I thought it would line things up properly, but what I ended up with was grayscale and had vertical while lines throughout. It's also flipped on both axes, but that was true before my changes, and can be solved by rotating the texture that pixels is given too later.

Edit: appended the calculation for the rgbX_Y variables to the top of the code block, per comment request. Also edited the numbers in the storing functions to reflect that I did in fact change those 3s to 4s

Comment: It looks like the multiplexing part here is because 3 doesn't divide into 4. So it shuffles 16 3-channel pixels into 3 registers `RGBR|GBRG|BRGB|RGBR` + `GBRG|BRGB|RGBR|GBRG` + `BRGB|RGBR|GBRG|BRGB` and writes those into memory. Since you want an alpha here, it's so much easier. You just need to shuffle your 16 4-channel pixels into _four_ registers of `RGBA|RGBA|RGBA|RGBA` and store those into memory.

Comment: How are `rgbX_Y` calculated? Please make your question self contained. The link may get invalid in the future and not everyone is willing to click it.

Comment: I hope you've got a simple straight C version working, so you have something to compare to (i.e. you can write some unit tests).

Comment: @paddy that's the part I'm not sure on. clearly creating a dedicated alpha pack isnt right, so I need to apply the alpha and the RGB channels across the 4 packs yes? And I'm not sure how to adjust what's here.

Comment: @chtz I'll add the rgbX_Y calc to the post. Do you recommend putting the whole function in in the future? I thought it would make the post prohibitively long.

Comment: @Conner It is generally recommended to provide a [mre], i.e. something which compiles on its own and describes the problem. If you think some parts are not relevant, write a function which takes (or reads) them as input parameters (but describe what these inputs are). And as paddy wrote, in this case it is much easier to pack the `r1..4`, `g1..4`, `b1..4` inputs directly.

Comment: @chtz Will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks

Comment: @connor Your "dedicated alpha pack" is no doubt responsible for the vertical lines you're seeing (an example image would be useful to show), because the way you've done it every iteration writes 48 bytes of consecutive RGB-packed data followed by 16 bytes of `0xff`. You need to familiarize yourself with exactly what all those shuffle and pack instructions do, so that you can understand how the data arrived as nice RGB triples in the first place. Only then will it become clear how to rewrite this part to insert alpha channels in the right places. I guarantee it'll be cleaner than the original.